# Where can I ask questions related to editing of videos?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I wanted to add `fade in` and `fade out` effects to videos. A quick google search didn't yield desired results. Is there a stack where I can ask questions related to `video editing and effects`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try at **[Audio Video Production (beta)](https://video.stackexchange.com/)**